# Best way to ensure a user installing something has correct .Net version installed

Tags: installation, .net, c#

I have written a small utility which requires .Net 4.5 to run. I have used InstallForge to create an installer package, but to my knowledge you can't set this up to check for .Net versions as with some of the paid installers.

What's the best approach (for free) to check the user has the right .net version installed? I considered writing a second utility to check for the right version. i.e.

Utility A = My main utility

Utility B = Framework tester

Workflow would be that program shortcut points to Utility B - if framework is found it calls Utility A. Otherwise gives user instruction to download latest .Net version.

However, this seems complex and a little inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just create a ClickOnce installation and be done with it?  That's free with any version of Visual Studio, as far as I know.

Comment: Pay for the full version of InstallForge or use another program to create your installs (InnoSetup supports Pascal Scripting in which you could check the installed .NET Version).

Answer (score 0):

A **bootstrapper** is a setup utility which coordinates the installation of dependencies before installing the main product. Several exist, but the simplest and most useful one I've found is [dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/).

- The editor has built-in templates for checking for and installing various .NET Framework versions.
- The default GUI is limited, but there's a second htmlInstaller GUI which is more flexible.